# How to clear the Offline Files cache on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, offline-files

We had a server rename/migration and I was using the Offline Files feature on Windows XP SP2.

Every so often, my "Offline Files Status" icon appears in my Taskbar and let's me know that the old server is "Offline: Unavailable to reconnect".

I have since pointed the Offline files to the new server, however my Offline Files still seems "attached" to the old server for some reason.

When I look in the "Offline Files Folder" on my PC, there is NO reference to the old server, so it must be stuck somewhere.

How do I get this corrected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cache is in `%SystemRoot%\CSC` folder, but MS says you shouldn't edit that manually. Here's the KB to re-initialize the cache:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230738

You could also <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-click the "Delete Files" button in the "Offline Files" tab under explorer->Tools->Options.

If you just want to sync to the new server, `csccmd.exe /moveshare`, from the Win 2k3 resource kit, should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

I have also used

`csccmd.exe /delete:\\server\share\path /recurse2`

on stubborn offline files.  I normally do this as a last resort, starting with the GUI first.

Answer (score 1):

Open an Explorer window, Tools, Synchronize, Setup. You should be able to see the shares that your system is connecting to, and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can go to the `%windir%\CSC` folder, take its ownership and manually wipe the all contents of the folder.